# Explode pandas dataframe into separate rows by splitting column by newlines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe in which a column contains paragraphs of text. I wanted to explode the dataframe into separate rows by splitting the paragraphs of text into newlines. The paragraph of text may contain multiple new lines or carrier return characters as shown below. To simplify, i have created the following example

```
    A                                             B  index_col
0  A0                                            B0          0
1  A1  split this\n\n into \r\n separate \n rows \n          1
2  A2                                            B2          2
3  A3                                            B3          3
```

I have tried to split the series into multiple values and combine them into single column using the stack method. I am not able to get the desired output. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
b = pd.DataFrame(df['B'].str.split('\n').tolist(), index=df['index_col']).stack()
    b = b.reset_index()[[0, 'index_col']]
    b.columns = ['B', 'index_col']
```

```
Current output:
            B  index_col
0          B0          0
1  split this          1
2                      1
3     into \r          1
4   separate           1
5       rows           1
6                      1
7          B2          2
8          B3          3

Desired output:
            B  index_col
0          B0          0
1  split this          1
2     into             1
3   separate           1
4       rows           1
5          B2          2
6          B3          3
```

Comment: I think, if you replace "\n" & "\r" with blanks & do split (with spaces) & then run your code, you will get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A0','A1'],
                    'B':['B0', 'split this\n\n into \r\n separate \n rows \n'],
                   'index_col':[0,1]})
print (df)
    A                                             B  index_col
0  A0                                            B0          0
1  A1  split this\n\n into \r\n separate \n rows \n          1
```

Your solution should be changed with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) added `expand=True` to [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `DataFrame` and last fitler out empty strings from `B` by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('index_col')['B']
         .str.replace('\r', ' ')
         .str.split('\n', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .rename('B')
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index()[['B', 'index_col']]
         .query("B != ''"))
print (df1)
            B  index_col
0          B0          0
1  split this          1
3      into            1
4   separate           1
5       rows           1
```

For pandas 0.25+ is possible use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.replace('\r', ' ').str.split('\n')
df1 = df[['B', 'index_col']].explode('B').query("B != ''")
print (df1)
            B  index_col
0          B0          0
1  split this          1
1      into            1
1   separate           1
1       rows           1
```